# Getting words from a string of words with no spaces

Tags: php

I have a string, let's say it's a URL `carinsurancepricesonline.com`. Im trying to get all the words from that string like `car` `insurance` `prices` `online`.

I've got this

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class WordFinderHelper
{
    protected $words = [];

    public function find($string)
    {
        $this->loop($string);
        return $this->words;
    }

    public function loop($string)
    {
        $myword = $string;
        $word_length = strlen($myword);
        $myword_prediction = $myword[0] . $myword[1];

        Log::info('CURRENT STRING: ' . $string);

        for ($i = 2; $i < $word_length; $i++) {
            $myword_prediction .= $myword[$i];

            Log::info('------------');
            Log::info('LOOKUP: ' . $myword_prediction);

            if (pspell_check(pspell_new('en'), $myword_prediction)) {
                Log::info('FOUND: ' . $myword_prediction);
                $this->words[] = $myword_prediction;

                $newString = preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($myword_prediction, '/') . '/', '', $string);

                Log::info('NEW STRING: ' . $newString);
                Log::info('------------');
                $this->loop($newString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$words = (new WordFinderHelper())->find('carinsurancepricesonline.com');
dd($words);
```

This gives me the below...

But how can I make it better? How can I ignore `ins` and actually find `prices` and not `price`.

All thoughts welcome.

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => "car"
  1 => "ins"
  2 => "insurance"
  3 => "price"
  4 => "son"
  5 => "line"
  6 => "prices"
  7 => "online"
]
```

And this is the processing output.

```
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: carinsurancepricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: car
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: car
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: insurancepricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: insurancepricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: ins
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: ins
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: urancepricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: urancepricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: ura
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: uran
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: uranc
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urance
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancep
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepr
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepri
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepric
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: uranceprice
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: uranceprices
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepriceso
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepriceson
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonl
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonli
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonlin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonline
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonline.
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonline.c
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonline.co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: urancepricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insu
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insur
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insura
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insuran
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insuranc
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurance
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: insurance
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: pricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: pricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pri
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pric
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: price
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: price
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: sonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: sonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: son
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: son
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: line.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: line.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: lin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: line
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: line
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: .com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: .com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: .co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: .com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: line.
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: line.c
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: line.co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: line.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonl
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonli
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonlin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonline
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonline.
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonline.c
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonline.co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: sonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: prices
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: prices
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: online.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: online.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: onl
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: onli
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: onlin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: online
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: FOUND: online
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: NEW STRING: .com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: CURRENT STRING: .com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: .co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: .com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: online.
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: online.c
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: online.co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: online.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: priceso
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: priceson
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonl
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonli
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonlin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonline
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonline.
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonline.c
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonline.co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: pricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancep
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepr
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepri
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepric
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insuranceprice
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insuranceprices
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepriceso
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepriceson
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonl
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonli
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonlin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonline
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonline.
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonline.c
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonline.co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: insurancepricesonline.com
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: cari
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carins
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsu
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsur
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsura
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsuran
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsuranc
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurance
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancep
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepr
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepri
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepric
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsuranceprice
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsuranceprices
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepriceso
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepriceson
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonl
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonli
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonlin
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonline
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonline.
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonline.c
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonline.co
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: ------------
[2021-10-27 14:04:27] local.INFO: LOOKUP: carinsurancepricesonline.com
```

Comment: I don't know if this task can actually be perfected, but my thoughts are: 1. iterate the characters from the back of the string and work toward the front. 2. Go through all permutations (temporary arrays) of results which use all characters to form words then select the permutation that has the fewest strings/words.  Of course, there is no way to differentiate `fireman` from `fire` and `man` -- so you'll need to "settle" for "good enough" at some point.

Comment: You must have a big data for that to compare and search each string with word from that. It is so called data science to compare the data from other places.

Comment: Good luck with this. Here's a couple of examples where words strung together didn't give the results the authors expected: penisland.com (they sell pens), expertsexchange.com(an exchange between experts) and powergenitalia.it(Italian subidiary of PowerGen). Try writing code to pick the bones out of that!